# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension - rbnacl-libsodium 1.0.16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, msys2, pacman-package-manager

I was trying ***bundle install*** and my gem file has ***gem 'rbnacl-libsodium'*** it took some time for installation and got failed.

```
Using rbnacl 4.0.2
Fetching rbnacl-libsodium 1.0.16
Installing rbnacl-libsodium 1.0.16 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rbnacl-libsodium-1.0.16/ext/rbnacl
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20220514-18748-mpv5bm.rb extconf.rb
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-mingw64
checking host system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
```

When I try ridk install 3rd step is failing.

```
MSYS2 seems to be properly installed Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain ...
    > pacman -S --needed --noconfirm autoconf autoconf2.13 autogen automake-wrapper automake1.10 automake1.11 automake1.12 automake1.13 automake1.14 automake1.15 automake1.6 automake1.7 automake1.8 automake1.9 diffutils file gawk grep libtool m4 make patch pkg-config sed texinfo texinfo-tex wget mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libmangle-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git mingw-w64-x86_64-make mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-tools-git mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git 
error: target not found: automake1.10 
error: target not found: automake1.6 
error: target not found: automake1.7 
error: target not found: automake1.8 
error: target not found: automake1.9 
warning: diffutils-3.8-3 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: file-5.41-4 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: gawk-5.1.1-1 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: grep-1~3.0-3 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: m4-1.4.19-2 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: make-4.3-3 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: patch-2.7.6-1 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: sed-4.8-2 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: texinfo-6.8-4 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: texinfo-tex-6.8-4 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: wget-1.21.3-1 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils-2.38-2 is up to date -- skipping warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git-10.0.0.r14.ga08c638f8-1 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-11.3.0-1 is up to date -- skipping warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs-11.3.0-1 is up to date -- skipping warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git-10.0.0.r14.ga08c638f8-1 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-libmangle-git-10.0.0.r14.ga08c638f8-1 is up to date
    -- skipping 
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git-10.0.0.r14.ga08c638f8-1 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-make-4.3-1 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-tools-git-10.0.0.r14.ga08c638f8-1 is up to date -- skipping 
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git-10.0.0.r14.ga08c638f8-1 is up to date
    -- skipping 
Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain failed 
Installation failed: pacman failed
```